# Как определить нужен ли https?

Tags: https

Как определить нужен ли https сайту или нет ?
Сайт одной туристической приватной компании, возможно они будут принимать оплату черезе paypal. А так он просто являеться очень информативным, новостным, не более.

Comment: Если сайт информационный - то это больше рейтинговая вещь. Поисковики повышают релевантность и у посетителей больше доверия к защищенным сайтам. Минимальный сертификат стоит до 1000 рублей.

Comment: Как минимум, защищенный протокол влияет на ранжирование, больше шансов, что сайт поднимется в выдаче. Думаю, это будет только плюсом

Comment: А типы сертификатов никак не влияют ? просто там есть сертификаты с заоблачными ценами. А есть средние, попроще. Но в общем суть понял. Без сертификата никуда.

Comment: Если необходима просто базовая защита - то сойдет самый простой за 700-900 р. Выдается быстро - минимальная проверка на владение доменным именем. Если у вас к примеру мега портал, через который ежедневно проходят тысячи пользователей и столько же денег - то тут нужен сертификат с проверкой не только доменного имени, но и самой компании, ее деятельности с контактами директора. В итоге название компании будет прям в адресной строке по вверх сертификата https. Доверие к таким сертификатам больше.

Comment: @wedoca что за глупости с минимальными ценами. Есть Cloudflare с бесплатными сертификатами на 15 лет. Mozilla продавливает бесплатный Let's Encrypt. Цена вопроса - ноль. А в плюсах - повышение рейтинга и прием оплаты от многих систем, которые отвергают простой http.

Comment: Для компании 1к в год не космическая сумма! С бесплатными сертификатами не редки случаи когда после 16 месяцев после выдачи его отзывают или типа того, при этом из за не валидного сертификата сайт просто не открывается и может не явно не указывать ошибку. У меня такое было. Зачем рисковать? Себе дороже может быть.

Comment: @wedoca чушь, как есть. У нас такого не было. Выбирайте правильных поставщиков бесплатных сертификатов. Те двое, кого я упомянул, слишком монструозны, чтобы рисковать своей репутацией.

Comment: Понял, думаю средний сертификат им для старта в самый раз.

Comment: @wedoca все сертификаты, включая платные, нужно продлевать. платный dv сертификат *ничем* не отличается об бесплатного let's encrypt. т.е. в просто выбросите те самые 700-900 рублей за услугу выдачи, которую let's encrypt предоставляет бесплатно :)